# after successful data insert print the information to another page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

After saving my data to database I want to display the information entered by the user in another page (`printRegInfo.cshtml`). How can I do that?

```
public ActionResult Create(FirmServiceRegistrationViewModel firmServiceReg)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(db.ServicesModels, "ServiceId", "ServiceName");
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    FirmsModel frm_ = new FirmsModel();
                    frm_.Name = firmServiceReg.Name;                    
                    frm_.PropName = firmServiceReg.PropName;
                    frm_.Address = firmServiceReg.Address;
                    db.FirmsModels.Add(frm_);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    int frmId = frm_.FirmId;

                    FirmServiceRegistrationModel frmServReg = new FirmServiceRegistrationModel();
                    frmServReg.ServiceId_ = firmServiceReg.ServiceId;
                    frmServReg.FirmId_ = frmId;

                    db.FirmServiceRegistrationModels.Add(frmServReg);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }                
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Now on successful insert of data I want to pass the data entered by the user `[Name, PropName, Address]` to the view page say `printRegInfo.cshtml`. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the name of action do you need to redirect to.  Pls show it. Is it the same controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code just get entered info and carried to another page using temp data. Hence you need to cast the as per model data and populate in view.

```
 public ActionResult Create(FirmServiceRegistrationViewModel firmServiceReg)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(db.ServicesModels, "ServiceId", "ServiceName");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FirmsModel frm_ = new FirmsModel();
                frm_.Name = firmServiceReg.Name;                    
                frm_.PropName = firmServiceReg.PropName;
                frm_.Address = firmServiceReg.Address;
                db.FirmsModels.Add(frm_);
                db.SaveChanges();
                int frmId = frm_.FirmId;

                FirmServiceRegistrationModel frmServReg = new FirmServiceRegistrationModel();
                frmServReg.ServiceId_ = firmServiceReg.ServiceId;
                frmServReg.FirmId_ = frmId;

                db.FirmServiceRegistrationModels.Add(frmServReg);
                db.SaveChanges();

                TempData["FirmRegData"]=frm_;
            }                
            return RedirectToAction("printRegInfo","ControllerName");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

public ActionResult printRegInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            FirmsModel frm_ =(FirmsModel)TempData["FirmRegData"];

          // Here you will get all entered info.
             
            
         }                
            return view(frm_);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I have one confusion regarding `return RedirectToAction("printRegInfo","ControllerName");`. What is the first parameter here and you have already defined controller name as `printRegInfo()`. Please clarify.

Comment: The printRegInfo is the ActionResult name, the second parameter is whatever your controller name is